# Phonegap Android Back Button w/ Ionic and Angular

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm having issues disabling the back button for Android in a Phonegap project using Ionic Framework / Angular JS.  I have tried many other proposed solutions to no avail.  The problem is I have a 'Login' screen which is a modal (ionicModal), but Android users are able to use the back button to navigate away regardless of if they are logged in or not.

I tried disabling the Android Back button all together.  The event fires, but the page navigation still happens.  I feel like if this worked, this would be the ideal and most straight forward solution.  Here though, preventDefault() and stopPropagation() seem to have no effect.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    alert('back button triggered');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

I also tried disabling the navigation from within Angular by listening to $locationChangeStart and preventing that:

```
// Disable "Back" button on androids if user is on login screen
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(e) {
    if( true ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

This also seems to work, but yet somehow still does not prevent Android from hiding the modal and going to the previous screen.

Is there a proper way to disable the Android Back button when using Phonegap/Ionic/Angular?  It uses the Angular UI router, and the modal is not a route but rather an ionicModal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems that there is a boolean property named ["hardwareBackButtonClose"](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/controller/ionicModal/) that you can set on the modal to determine whether the modal can be closed using the hardware back button on Android and similar devices. Defaults to: true, so try setting it to false.

Comment: Just saw this myself.  I guess their code is moving a little quicker than their documentation.  That option didn't exist a little over a month ago when I initially started this project.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After starting to dig around the ionic code in GitHub, I saw they've recently added this as an option to the modal.  I was able to apply only the changes highlighted in this commit and get this working:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/commit/61f879bb535997078f73b7faa424e43699e0b018

Also add the following constant, per commit https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/commit/e9d8eba12b4de48617e9335e113c7c98173909b7

```
var PLATFORM_BACK_BUTTON_PRIORITY_MODAL = 200;
```